# Fire DLL event from another DLL (or Application)

Tags: c#, events, dll

I have 2 projects. In the first:

```
public delegate _Event(int code);
public event _Event TestEvent;
```

now I want to do something like this in my second project

```
public void TestFunc()
{
   TestEvent(11); //Project1.MyClass.TestEvent(11);
}
```

namely I want to fire Project1's event form Project2. Can anybody help me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You're missing the return type on the delegate.

2.You can fire the event from within the declaring type only.
What you can do is declare a public method on the type which declares the event which fires it.

```
public delegate void _Event(int code);
public event _Event TestEvent;
public void FireEvent(int val){TestEvent(val);}
```

Comment: oh, yes. after i posted, i have solved it like this but this is a true answer :) thanks!